# Function $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, continuity

> Define a function $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{
> x}\left(\frac{1}{2}-t+[t]\right)\ dt$$
> where $[t]$ denotes the greatest integer function and $x\in[0,\infty)$ then prove that $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$.

I tried taking $c$ be any point in $[0,\infty)$ then $$ |f(c+h)-f(c)|=  \left|\int_{c}^{
c+h}\left(\frac{1}{2}-t+[t]\right)\ dt  \right|$$ So by triangle inequality$$ |f(c+h)-f(c)|\leq \int_{c}^{
c+h}\left|\frac{1}{2}-t+[t]\right|\ dt  $$
So we get by using $|t-[t]|\leq 1$ $$ |f(c+h)-f(c)|\leq \frac{3}{2} h  $$

So we get $$\lim_{h\to 0^+} f(c+h)=f(c)$$

Now we have
$$ |f(c-h)-f(c)|=  \left|\int_{c-h}^{
c}\left(\frac{1}{2}-t+[t]\right)\ dt  \right|$$ So by triangle inequality$$ |f(c-h)-f(c)|\leq \int_{c-h}^{
c}\left|\frac{1}{2}-t+[t]\right|\ dt  $$
So we get by using $|t-[t]|\leq 1$ $$ |f(c-h)-f(c)|\leq \frac{3}{2} h  $$

So we get $$\lim_{h\to 0^+} f(c-h)=f(c)$$

So we have $$\lim_{h\to 0^+} f(c+h)=\lim_{h\to 0^+} f(c-h)=     f(c)$$

Is my attempt fine? Any changes needed?

Comment: It's OK but could be simpler. Let $g(t)=1/2-t+[t].$ Then $|g(t)|\le 1/2 .$ So $|f(x+h)-f(x)|\le |h|/2.$ Reference topic: Lipschitz-continuous functions.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks. So is every Lipschitz continuous function continuous?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet How did we get $|g(t)|\leq 1/2$? We have $|t-[t]\leq 1$. So should'nt it be $|g(t)|\leq 3/2$?

Comment: Since $t\geq 0$, we have $|t-[t]|=t-[t]$ which is between 0 and 1, so $-\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{2}_t+[t]\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Marija Thanks a lot.